# Give developer access to selected files and folders

Tags: git, codeigniter

I have an application developed in Codeigniter and want to hire different developers for different functionalities on the application.

I don't want to give full access to all developers lest they copy and sell to competitor, as I have invested a lot of time and money in this application.

So far I have implemented this partially by restricting the ftp access to a particular folder, but then they get all files access in that folder, which is not an ideal solution.
I have created a dev env using the copy of production code.

Now, is there a way I can give access to a particular file using git (if needed) and the developers can update that and commit that code from git and the changes are pushed to my server, and they can test it.

I will really appreciate your inputs and suggestions.

Edit 1: So far, I have learnt that I will need to create a private repo for every developer who will push and commit their changes to the code on git and from git, I will need to create a pipeline to deploy those changes to the test/prod server.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, is there a way I can give access to a particular file using git ...

No.  Git is about *commits*.  Every commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  If you give someone a commit, they have access to all the files in that commit.  If you don't give someone a commit, they have none of the files.  To give someone some particular subset of files that go with one or more commits, you need to use something outside of Git.

Comment: Thanks @torek. Do you think creating a private repo would help in this case and using a CI/CD tool to pull the changes upon commit would solve the purpose?

Comment: Not really, no. You'd need to create a whole slew of private repositories, one for each group, and do your own custom integration. That's possible, but depending on language and tools, potentially quite painful.